# What's the fastest, easiest, and simplest way to convert my Oracle Apex web app to a non-web-based app?

Tags: android, windows, oracle-apex

I have a completed web app in Oracle Apex. I need it to be software that gets installed on a user's device and creates a database on it too, meaning no internet is required to run the app whatsoever. Would love it if I can do this in one go on multiple platforms too, meaning I can make it available to install on Android, Windows, and iOS.

Comment: I am not expert on this but as an idea, you can research Xamarin, Cordova etc. that makes your website an installable app using webview etc.

Comment: @cengizsevimli isn't that just a progressive web app? That means it's still a web app just running in its own window instead of the user's browser.

Answer (score 2):

APEX itself is *server-side* code. The runtime engine is written in proprietary PL/SQL and is *in* the database; it produces all of the HTML code dynamically at runtime based on stored configurations. It is specifically designed *not* to be a client-side app. Most browser-based apps can't even interact with the client operating system, because of security features built into all modern browsers. Why would you pick APEX (or *any* browser-based framework!) as a development tool if your requirement was for a client-side application?

You can run an APEX app out of the free Oracle XE edition on a client, but a lot of people - especially business/corporations - won't allow database services like that to run on workstations or laptops because of the potential security vulnerabilities it would introduce. The user would also need admin privileges and some technical expertise themselves to install and configure everything required. Most often, any true database service will require network connectivity to a remote server *somewhere*, even if on the local/on-premise network and not the public Internet. Note that it would still run in a browser, and not be able to interact directly with the client operating system.

If you want a true client-side app with an embedded database that runs on lots of platforms with no network connectivity, then you'll have to pick a built-for-client-side development framework (probably Java, given your requirements) and start from scratch to move all of your business logic into the new language. This is not a trivial task:

- Native SQL and PL/SQL in APEX allow you potentially to do a lot of things with data set operations that other languages will just not do nearly as efficiently.
- The APEX low-code paradigm simplifies a lot of basic UI design issues that would have to be more built from scratch in other development frameworks.
- The APEX low-code paradigm handles a lot of the business logic automatically or allows you to build that logic directly into the *database itself* (where it really belongs), as with triggers, table constraints, role-based privileges, or auditing, so you may not even have original code to "convert".
- Switching to another database other than Oracle will also be a challenge, as not all databases are created equal and most have distinctive differences in their SQL syntax and object capabilities.

Bottom line is that there is no automated way to achieve what you're asking: you will have learn and work in a completely different development paradigm, language, and database engine appropriate to your requirements and start over.

Comment: Ok so how do I start from scratch? What platform should I use to create the app? Surely some platforms allow embedding a database into an app and accessing it using SQL no? I already know multiple programming languages, and most SQL languages are also trivially different.

Comment: Also I would prefer if the database was embedded in the app instead of the user having to install Oracle XE since I've tried the Oracle XE installation process on a laptop myself and it's extremely difficult.

Comment: @NumaleSoybea your problem has no simple/easy/fast solution. For each platform you wish to convert your app to, you should study which option is the best. I don't think there is a way to create 1 app that runs on Winsows, Android and iOS, most likely it is going to be multiple apps built on different technologies.

Comment: Ok then Windows. How do I create it specifically for Windows? Does Visual Studio have a method to create an app with an embedded database?

Comment: You will have to research database engines that can be embedded within your specific development paradigm: the database will not be a native part of the programming language. I would again (just my opinion) recommend Java as your programming language given the number of platforms you want to support. There may be a Java-based embedded DB you can use. That is opinion-based conjecture on my part and not really the purpose of this forum.

Comment: Also note that embedded databases generally deal with very small amounts of data, relatively speaking. If you plan on having a lot of data, you may not be able to get away from the network requirement and a separate database server.